Convergence of multivariate normal distributions
Consider a sequence of $k$-dimensional random vectors $\mu_n$ and $k \times k$ random matrices $\Sigma_n$ which are positive definite.
For each realization of $(\mu_n,\Sigma_n)$, call it $(\mu^{(i)}_n, \Sigma^{(i)}_n)$,
define a multivariate normal random variable $X_n^{(i)} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_n^{(i)},\Sigma_n^{(i)})$.
If $\mu_n \to \mu$ in probability and $\Sigma_n \to \Sigma$ in probability, what can I say about how the random variable $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n^{(i)}$?
Can I say $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n^{(i)} \to X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ in distribution, for almost all $i$? Or some variant of it?

What do you mean by convergence in probability ? $\mu_n, \Sigma_n$ are determined vectors, matrices

@ThànhNguyễn Thank you for the comment. Yes, I have updated the problem statement. I hope it makes more sense now, if not, let me know and we can try to refine it. The point is, the random variable I am considering is drawn from a distribution that has parameters which are themselves fluctuating. But in the fluctuations become weaker in a limit. Maybe I did not have to introduce each realisation $i$

Okay, the problem statement makes sense now.

@ThànhNguyễn Yes, essentially $X_n$ is drawn from a distribution which has itself random parameters. But I have knowledge that the random parameters converge in probability to some fixed values (in $n$). I would like to understand how $X_n$ is distributed in that limit.
